Issue while signature verification in Fido server while authentication
I am trying to implement passkeys authentication using Java Fido server and JS Webauthn api. While authenticating i am getting the signature verification error.
Here is the stack trace,
java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 71 but was expecting 256
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:213) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1435) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:789) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.webauthn.crypto.signature.SignatureVerifier.validate(SignatureVerifier.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.webauthn.webauthn.assertion.validation.signature.AssertionSignatureVerifier.verify(AssertionSignatureVerifier.java:84) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.webauthn.controller.fido.FidoAuthnAuthenticationController.authenticateFinal(FidoAuthnAuthenticationController.java:115) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]

I have this code section already working earlier, but now it starts giving me this issue. Anybody please assist me, is there any changes or upgradations in the signing algorithm or something else similar in WebAuthn api that helps me resolve this issue.


got 71 but was expecting 256

71 bytes is probably an ECDSA P-256 signature, and 256 bytes is probably an RSA signature. So you're getting an ECDSA signature and trying to verify it as an RSA signature.
The public-key algorithm used is controlled by pubKeyCredParams during the create call.
